# how can i add .capitalize in this code to capitalize only the first word of my reversed string

Tags: python, recursion

```
def reverse(s):
    if Len(s) == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return reverse(s[1:]) + s[0]

s = ""

print("the string : ",end="")
print(s)
print("reversed string: ",end="")
print(reverse(s))
```

Comment: BTW: A far more efficient reverse would be `s[::-1]`

Answer (score 3):

Call `capitalize` on the string that's returned by `reverse`:

```
>>> reverse("The quick brown fox")
'xof nworb kciuq ehT'
>>> reverse("The quick brown fox").capitalize()
'Xof nworb kciuq eht'
```

No need to split it out by word since the first letter of the string will necessarily be part of the first word also.